# Web-scraping - CSS Selector returning 0

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

I am following the automate the boring stuff course on Udemy, and am attempting to scrape the price of bitcoin from binance. However, when using the CSS selector the value I get is always 0.

```
 import requests, bs4
 res = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/en')
 res.raise_for_status()
 
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
 elems = soup.select('#top_crypto_table-2-BTC_BUSD > div.css-11d5f40')
 
 elems[0].text.strip()
  
 '0'
```

Comment: Hello Blake, could you clarify what the expected value is?

Comment: I don't think you can get those values, Those are constantly changing. Try Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup will not work in this case since those values are being updated constantly by JavaScript.

You need to try Selenium and get the data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests, bs4

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver.exe", options=options)


driver.get('https://www.binance.com/en')

 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
elems = soup.select_one('#top_crypto_table-2-BTC_BUSD > div.css-11d5f40')
print(elems.text.strip())
```

The value as of now.

```
$46,877.79
```